# Detect if DOM element has really an attribute defined in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, internet-explorer-8

The following example is tested in IE8

I have a very simple list like this

```
<select>
   <option>opt 1</option>
   <option>opt 2</option>
</select>
```

Assuming that `this` refer to the DOM element of the first option. When I do `this.selected` it returns `true` even when it's not. What I want is a function that return `true` only when the DOM has the attribute `selected` or `selected="selected"` explicitly defined by the user/coder.

I cannot use `hasAttribute` because it's not defined in ie8.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selected` property on option elements is `true` if the option is currently selected in the select box. In the markup, you can make an option selected by specifying the `selected` attribute, but there are other ways for the option to become selected in a select box (the user can choose it, the browser may make the first option selected by default, and so on). Note that bit about the default. In a drop-down select box, nearly all (all?) browsers will make the first option selected automatically if you didn't put the `selected` attribute on any of them.

So `this.selected` does reliably tell you whether the element is selected.

Unfortunately, IE8's `getAttribute` will return `"selected"` for the `"selected"` attribute even if the markup doesn't have it, if the element is selected. Most other browsers won't do this, they understand the difference between a property and an attribute, but sadly IE8 does not.

Fortunately, jQuery's `attr` function has a workaround for this (since you've tagged your question `jquery`). `attr` will return `undefined` (rather than `null`) if the element doesn't have that attribute, even on IE8. So if you really want to know, you can find out that way. But it's rare to care about that. (Note: The workaround is [in v1.10.2](http://jsbin.com/OvipABOr/1) but apparently [not in v1.7.2](http://jsbin.com/OvipABOr/2); those links are really only meaningful if you use IE8 to view them.)

But the normal way to read the value of a select box in jQuery is to use `.val` on the select box element.

Comment: I tried jquery 1.7.2 but the problem still exist. Even when I do `this.outerHTML`, IE8 added `<option selected></option>` on its own.

Comment: @ThanhTrung: This is the joy of using up-to-date stuff. jQuery 1.10.2 has the necessary workaround: http://jsbin.com/OvipABOr/1 It looks like jQuery 1.7.2 (very out of date!) doesn't: http://jsbin.com/OvipABOr/2

Comment: This guy had the same problem. This should give us a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361446/ie8-the-option-tag-gets-a-selected-attribute-by-default-and-clonenode-makes I'll try and see how `.attr` is implemented in the lastest jquery. Thanks. I'll give you credit when my tests are done

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery, then:

```
var value = $('select').val();
```

This would return the attribute value of the selected option, or in case there is no value, the label (the text inside the option tag).

Comment: I don't want to know the selected option. I only want to know if the DOM element has an attribute `selected` explicitely defined or not (and not internally defined)

Comment: Then using jQuery:

    var attr = $('#element').attr('selected');

If attr === undefined then the attribute is not defined.

Comment: This should work on other browsers but IE8. The main problem here is about IE8 first option is automatically selected

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function check() {
   return document.getElementsByTagName('select').selectedIndex > -1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, selectedIndex always throws 0 even when none `selected` attribute is specified in any option

Comment: @ThanhTrung: `0` is the first option in the list. If *none* were selected, `selectedIndex` would be `-1`.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a IE8 bug thing. Need a workaround

Comment: @ThanhTrung `0` is the first position or the first option in select. if you check my condition `> -1` .. this `selectedIndex` will return -1 if in case of not selected and will return the index in case of selected

Comment: I know. That's by definition, the specification of W3C. But IE8 doesn't respect things like usual. Did you test on IE8?